Regex for replacing chars that appear two times or more in java
I am doing exercises online and came across a question that tasked me with removing all the characters that appeared in the string 2 or more times.
For example:
String s2 = "racecar"; 

would become "e", and
String s3 = "aabbccc"; 

would become "", and
String s4 = "Hello world";

would become "He wrd"
I know there are other solutions, but I'm wondering if there is a regex for this.
I tried a few different things:
s = s.replaceAll(".{2,}", "");
s = s.replaceAll("[a-z]{2,}", "");

and a few other, but all seems to replace the entire string, and I only want to replace all chars that appear more than one time.
So, is there a regular expression for this?

What makes you think that this is a job for a regex?

For input string s: Map<Integer, Long> counts = s.codePoints().boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(codep -> codep, Collectors.counting()));String unique = s.codePoints().filter(Character::isLetter).filter(c ->counts.get(c) == 1).mapToObj(Character::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());

Or Map<String, Long> counts = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\b{g}")) .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ch -> ch, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting())); counts.values().removeIf(count -> count != 1); String unique = String.join("", counts.keySet()); For ASCII input, split("") would do but outside this simple world, the meaning of a character can be quite complicated…

You could use a regex "(.)(.*?)\1" to find a duplicated character, then replace that duplicate with empty string. This needs to be repeated in a loop until there are no more matches:
static String removeDuplicatedChars(String s) {
    var m = Pattern.compile("(.)(.*?)\\1").matcher("");
    while(m.reset(s).find()) {
        s = s.replace(m.group(1), "");
    }
    return s;
}

However it would be simpler to solve using simple iteration and append to result when s.indexOf(ch) == s.lastIndexOf(ch).

Here are two using regex and some others sans regex. This
just creates a matcher to match the regex and remove the duplicates. The string must be reassigned and reset for subsequent tests and printout.
String[] testCases = {"racecar","foobar","this is a test","lengthy"};

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(.)(.*)\\1");
for (String s : testCases) {
   Matcher m = pat.matcher(s);
   while (m.find()) {
       m.reset(s = s.replace(m.group(1),""));
   }
   System.out.println(s);
}

prints
e
fbar
hae
lengthy

The next one is similar except it uses the location of the first character match to start the next search. It uses the previous regex.
Matcher m = pat.matcher(s);
int start = 0;
while (m.find(start)) {
     start = m.start()+1;
     s = s.replace(m.group(1), "");
}

Here are some non-regex solutions. They print the same values as above.

find the index of the current character.  It must be >= 0 since the test case is the source.
then if that same character is found after that index, remove all such occurences.

for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
     int i = s.indexOf(ch);
     if (s.indexOf(ch, i + 1) != -1) {
         s = s.replace(ch+"", "");
     }
 }
 System.out.println(s);


Here, a hashSet is used to keep track of characters as they are added.
if the add method returns false, the character is already in the set so it must be a duplicate so remove all occurrences.

 Set<Character> seen = new HashSet<>();
 for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
     if (!seen.add(ch)) {
         s = s.replace(ch+"", "");
     }
 }
 System.out.println(s);

And lastly, here is one that just uses a count of characters seen.  It removes all the characters when the count reaches 2.
 int[] count = new int[128];
 for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
     if (++count[ch] == 2) {
         s = s.replace(ch+"", "");
     }
 }

Note that the non-regex solutions are more efficient as regex processing is convenient but expensive.

The pattern (.).*\\1.* would find such a duplicate. However on an input from length n it needs n² steps. It has a quadratic complexity. For a 1 K text 1,000,000 steps would be needed.
I did not see a perfect answer, so mine which is not quadratic:
static String uniques(String s) {
    Set<Integer> alreadyFound = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
    s.codePoints()
        .forEach(cp -> {
            if (!alreadyFound.add(cp)) {
                duplicates.add(cp);
            }
        });
    // That needed O(n log n) steps. (Mind, HashSet
    // optimally tends to result in O(n).)
    int[] codePoints = s.codePoints()
        .filter(cp -> !duplicates.contains(cp))
        .toArray();
    // Also O(n log n).
    return new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
}

String s2 = "racecar";
System.out.println(uniques(s2));

The above also handles more complex scripts by using not char (UTF-16) but int code points, full Unicode (UTF-32).

Processing codepoints still doesn’t handle composed characters. If you want to support complex scripts, you’d need something like string.split("\\b{g}") and process the elements as strings. Further, while it might be correct to say the stream operation performing hash lookups has O(n log n) (the worst case), it will be irritating to most users. And I don’t see any reason why the string constructor, performing a linear copy, should have O(n log n). This makes no sense.

@Holger I actually appreciate your criticism. Composed and clustered code points I assumed to be a too side tracking issue, though_code points_ themselves worth while. Text normalization and/or the BreakIterator would be to consider. I am afraid that a "solution" would become a beast. **Your comment with \\b{g} would best be given as answer; I overlooked it - that regex can do that! I assume that it is a grapheme break, which I did not know. Thanks.

I dont think regex is the right fit here. it can be easily solved with the use of Set/HashSet (if the order is not important). otherwise we can use LinkedHashSet to preserve the order. Time Complexity would be O(n)
Solution:
Step 1: Create two LinkedHashSet objects. one for holding the duplicates and the other for holding the unique values
Step 2: Iterate over the string and compare to see if this character is alreadt present in the duplicateList or in the unique list
Step 3: if the character is not in duplicateList, then try to add to the uniqueList
Step 4: if the character is present in the duplicateList or we are not able to add it to uniqueList, then Remove it from uniqueList and add it to the duplicateList
Example :
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      //System.out.println("Hello, World!");
      printUniqueChasr("Hello World!");
  }
  
   public static void printUniqueChasr(String input) {
        LinkedHashSet<Character> uniqueChars = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        LinkedHashSet<Character> duplicateChars = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
                      System.out.println(c);
            if (!duplicateChars.contains(c)) {
                if (uniqueChars.add(c)) {
                    // Character is unique
                } else {
                    // Character is a duplicate
                    uniqueChars.remove(c);
                    duplicateChars.add(c);
                }
            }
        }
        
      System.out.println(uniqueChars);
    }
}


The OP wrote "I am doing exercises online and came across a question that tasked me with removing all the characters that appeared in the string 2 or more times." Although Strings are immutable, the requirement is clear.  You need to return a string that has the offending characters removed.
